# Create hive table from another existing table without defining schema

Tags: hive

I have table Employee in hive which is partitioned.
Now i want to copy  all the contents from `Employee` to another table without defining any schema like:
My first table is like:
`create table Employee(Id String,FirstName String,Lastname String);`
But i don't want to define the same schema for the `NewEmployee` table:
`create table Newemployee(Id String,FirstName String,LastName String);`

Answer (score 4):

Since, you have not mentioned any partitioning details so I am assuming that it does not have any significance. Please correct me, if I am wrong.

The query that you are looking for would be like this:

`create table Newemployee as select * from Employee;`

Comment: Just accept this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below code:

```
Create table dbname.tablename LIKE existing_table_or_Viewname LOCATION hdfs-path
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE NewEmployee
   [ROW FORMAT SERDE] (if any)
   [STORED AS] Format
   AS
SELECT * FROM Employee [SORT BY];

Rules while create table as create 
    1. The target table cannot be a partitioned table.
    2. The target table cannot be an external table.
    3. The target table cannot be a list bucketing table.